# Search a specific database field with CakePHP post method

Tags: php, search, cakephp

I’m trying to implement a simple search into an application, but not sure of the best way to handle this. My database contains a Listings object which includes City field. I want to create a search form where the user inputs a city into a text field and gets all of the Listings for that city on the next page. I don’t want to perform a full-text search, just the query on that City field.

Also, on the results page, I’d like to store the query in POST and can’t figure out the best way to do this.

What is the best way to approach this in the controller?

Comment: I'd suggest you start with this question :)

Answer (score 1):

Well your view would look something like this

```
$this->Form->Create('Listing', array('action'=>'search'));
$this->Form->input('city', array('default'=>$city));
$this->Form->end();

if (isset($listings)) {
//code to display listings
}
```

This view would create the correct form. And your controller needs to get that value

```
function search() {
   $city = '';
   if (!empty($this->data)) {
      $city  = $this->data['Listing']['city'];
      $opts  = array(
          'conditions' => array('Listing.city' => $city)
      );
      $listings   = $this->Listing->find('all', $opts); 
      $this->set('listings', $listings);
   }
   $this->set('city', $city); // so the keyword is saved. Can also get it via $this->data
}
```

This code should give you an idea on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great tutorial with a [CakePHP search plugin](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FAVuLXFVaCw) tutorial. You can download the full working code as well from [github](https://github.com/OldWest/cakephp-search-plugin-v1.1) (w/ MySQL dump).

Answer (score 0):

View:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create() 

echo $this->Form->input('search');

?>

<input name="data[Product][word]" />
```

controller:

```
<?php 

    $result = $this->Product->find('all',array(
        'conditions'=>array(
            'OR'=>array(
                array('name LIKE'=>'%'.$word.'%'),
                array('description LIKE'=>'%'.$word.'%'))))); 


    $this->set(compact('result'));

?>
```

Comment: Explain your code too. Is this the best way (as asked)? And why?